# Will these LinkedList nodes be eligible for garbage collection?

Tags: java, garbage-collection, linked-list

I am implementing my own `LinkedList`. Right now, I'm on the `clear()` function which removes all of the elements from the list.

Here is my code so far:

```
public class LinkedList<E> {
    // the first element of this LinkedList
    private Node start;

    // the last element of this LinkedList
    private Node end;

    // the number of elements that constitute this LinkedList
    private int length;

    private class Node {
        private Node last;
        private Node next;

        private E data;

        // each Node has a reference to the previous Node and
        // the next Node. The first element of the LinkedList
        // will have a null reference to the previous element
        // and the last element will have a null reference to
        // the next element. Each Node stores a piece of data
        // in the data variable.
    }

    public void clear() {
        start = null;
        end = null;

        length = 0;
    }

    // other methods omitted
}
```

In the `clear()` function, I set the `start` and `end` references to `null`. I am unsure how this will affect the nodes in the middle of the linked list (or even the `start` and `end` nodes).

If I have four nodes (or more) in my `LinkedList`, the middle two (or more) will point to each other. Once I set `start` and `end` to `null`, my code doesn't have any references to those objects anymore, but they have references to each other.

Will these middle nodes, or even the start and end nodes, be eligible for garbage collection or not, and why?

Bonus question: how could I figure this out experimentally?

Comment: http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/root/jdk/openjdk/6-b14/java/util/LinkedList.java#LinkedList.clear%28%29

Comment: You an check out your programs heap using `jvisualvm`, a tool located in the bin folder of your JDK. You can also call the GC from the program.

Comment: Yes, this will be GC'd correctly.  Generally speaking, trust that the GC is smarter than you.

Comment: Can you provide some sort of explanation/proof to your answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems to me like you are worrying about the wrong thing here. GC will track all *roots* and clear children for them also. For you example this would mean that as soon as LinkedList is not used by active Threads, it will be eligible for Garbage Collection, even if **children** will point to some real data (Nodes in your case). What is the use of having an Object that is not needed anymore even if it relates itself to some data?

```
 LinkedList
    |   |

Node1  Node2
```

if LinkedList is Garbage Collected, so will the Nodes, you do not have to worry about this. Thus your clear method has to reset the LinkedList to a default, empty one and not worry about GC.

P.S. You might want to read how GC works, at least to understand roots.

Comment: This is still true even with a doubly-linked list, correct?

Comment: @mathguy54 yes. that is the whole point of having a garbage collector, so that you do not worry about things like these.

Answer (score 0):

Do not set null to the objects explicitly ... you create linked list object in some scope and when the scope is over it(along with nodes) is eligible to be garbage collected.

If its a web application write finalize() to log a message.